# Há como especificar uma hash, versão ou assinatura ao executar o `npx` (do npm)?

Tags: javascript, segurança, npm

Estou criando um gerador para gerar algumas páginas estáticas em HTML. Porém, me deparei com a situação de ter que utilizar o [NPX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) para utilizar o [AMP Optimizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ampproject/toolbox-cli).

Eu posso executar o comando da seguinte forma:

```
exec.Command("npx", "@ampproject/toolbox-cli", "optimize", "nome_do_arquivo.html")
```

Existem outras formas que posso fazer isso, mas de qualquer maneira o problema parece persistir em todos os casos.

---

**O problema é que isso obtem o `@ampproject/toolbox-cli` que pode ser qualquer arquivo.** Não há qualquer tipo de assinatura, hash ou versão especifica. O Golang, por exemplo, inclui um `go.sum` que permite verificar as hashes, dessa forma se o conteúdo baixado for diferente ele irá falhar. Isso é, ao executar o `go run cmd/generate.go` ele baixará exatamente aquilo que quero, ou falhará se a hash/timestamp for distinto.

---

Existe alguma forma de verificar a integridade do `@ampproject/toolbox-cli` e só executar se a hash for igual à uma especifica, por exemplo?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe a possibilidade de se fornecer uma versão específica do pacote a ser instalado pelo `npx`.

Da [documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx), você pode utilizar assim:

```
npx [options] <command>[@version] [command-arg]...
```

Quanto ao *hash* de integridade ou algum tipo de assinatura, não achei nenhum tipo de referência que indicasse suporte pelo `npx`.

---

Por exemplo:

```
$ npx create-react-app@4.0.3 --version
4.0.3
```

Mas se eu especificar uma versão diferente:

```
$ npx create-react-app@2.1.8 --version
2.1.8
```

---

Como, uma vez que publicados ao npm, pacotes podem somente ser apagados (e não modificados), penso que especificar a versão, de modo *hard-coded*, já sirva como uma barreira de segurança adicional. Decerto o tipo de preocupação demonstrado na pergunta é importante.

Claro, ainda há a possibilidade de invasão aos servidores do npm, mas ignoremos isso pelo nosso próprio bem. ;)

Comment: Continuo achando estranho não haver como especificar a hash do arquivo, acho que é confiar demais no NPM. :|